# file size increase in blender

Tags: export, import

I make a bus model in blender a month ago. Now when I import this file in blender and then export it without any change its size changed from 2 Mb to 17.7 MB and the file is in fbx format and I export it in fbx also. I am using blender version 2.79.
kindly guide me in this,

Comment: What is its original format? Did you maybe apply any modifiers? Specify the fbx formats, there are many versions (ascii/binary, 2014/15, 2016, ...).

Comment: fbx 7.4 binnary .not apply any modifier just import and export

Comment: FBX  7.4 BINARY DIDNOT APPLY ANY MODIFIER JUST IMPORT AND EXPORT

Comment: can you add screenshot of the import and export settings?